# How to access to other fields by refering data structure name

Tags: c#

I want to have data structure that by refering it's name, I have access to other fields.

for example:

```
value1: "21", "value 1", "AAA"
value2: "23", "value 2", "BBB"
value3: "35", "value 3", "CCC"
```

I want to have access to data structure like this:

```
MyStructure.value1 -- > return "value 1" and "AAA"
```

what data structure do u prefer?
Thanks for any helping

Comment: Please reword your question. It is not clear what you're asking. Note that C# does not support syntax extensions like C and C++ do beyond simple operator-overloading.

Comment: @Dai I want to create a class for managing error description in my program for displaing to user. I want to save the code of error and description in 2 languages. its better that I create list? or 3d array? or structure? ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to store error descriptions in multiple languages. Do not embed your human-readable strings within your program code, instead use Resource files. I will not explain how to use them, instead I'll refer you to search online for ".net resources localization" to find plenty of articles and tutorials.

Create a resource file for each language (give it an appropriate name), then add the messages to file. I suggest using an enum as a key (technically, the enum's `ToString()` value would be used as the key, like so:

```
enum ErrorMessage {
    OutOfMemory,
    PEBCAK,
    IdTenTError,
    // etc...
}

public static class ResourceHelper {
     public static String GetMessage(ErrorMessage message) {
          String key = "ErrorMessage_" + message.ToString();
          return ResourceManager.GetString( key );
     }
}
```

Your English (en-US) resource file would contain this:

```
ErrorMessage_OutOfMemory  "Out of memory"
ErrorMessage_PEBCAK      "er..."
ErrorMessage_IdTenTError "Who is writing these error messages?"
```

and repeat for other languages, e.g. fr-FR:

```
ErrorMessage_OutOfMemory  "Manque de mémoire"
ErrorMessage_PEBCAK      "Problème existe entre chaise et le clavier"
ErrorMessage_IdTenTError "Moins on en dit mieux"
```

The `ResourceManager.GetString` method chooses the language to use from the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property. You can overrride this with the `GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)` overload to force-select the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    class Foo
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();
   dictionary.Add("21", new Foo { Value = "value 1", OtherValue = "AAA" });
   dictionary.Add("23", new Foo { Value = "value 2", OtherValue = "BBB" });
   dictionary.Add("35", new Foo { Value = "value 3", OtherValue = "CCC" })
   var foo = dictionary["21"]; 
   //foo.OtherValue 
   //foo.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to map a value to a complex object. This is best done using a Dictionary. First you have to design the class which holds all data for a single value:

```
class ErrorInfo
{
    public ErrorInfo(string descriptionEN, string descriptionDE)
    {
        DescriptionEN = descriptionEN;
        DescriptionDE = descriptionDE;
    }

    public string DescriptionEN {get; private set;}
    public string DescriptionDE {get; private set;}
}
```

Then you can define a dictionary which maps from error code to the associated ErrorInfo:

```
var dict = new Dictionar<string, ErrorInfo>();
```

You must also fill the dictionary:

```
dict.Add("1", new ErrorInfo("An error ocurred", "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten"));
dict.Add("2", new ErrorInfo("Unknown error", "Unbekannter Fehler"));
// etc.
```

Getting information of an error if you only have the error code is simple:

```
ErrorInfo info = dict["1"];
```

This approach can easily be extended by simply adding more properties to `ErrorInfo`